# URL linebreak in footnote

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, urls

I use a footnote with a too long url, so that I'd like to see a linebreak. The url package does linebreaks automatically as far as i know, but in the footnote it won't do it.
Anyone have a solution to this?

```
\footnote{\url{http://www.this-is-a-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-long.url/}}
```

Comment: In general `\url` does a good job in breaking the URL; this particular example can't be broken, because the hyphen is not a permissible point. Can you show the real URL?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 41):

The [`url` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) [documentation](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf) suggests the following:

> Ordinarily, breaks are not allowed after "-" characters because this
>   leads to confusion. (Is the "-" part of the address or just a hyphen?)
>   The package option `[hyphens]` allows breaks after explicit hyphen
>   characters. The `\url` command will never ever hyphenate words.

If your original example included a URL that has that specific structure, then `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` will solve your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
This is text\footnote{\url{http://www.this-is-a-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-long.url/}}.
\end{document}​
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. :( I am using `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}`

Comment: @Magne: Provide a minimal example that replicates the behaviour.

Comment: @Magne For me it works, if I put `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Answer (score 8):

> The url package does linebreaks automatically [in long URL strings], but in the footnote it won't do it.

The main issue -- not touched on by the previously-posted answers -- is that the `\url` macro is "fragile" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word). That's why typesetting URL strings -- especially long URL strings -- in footnotes can be tricky.

For just such cases, the user guide of the `url` package recommends the "defined-URL" approach, as it is "robust" -- again, the LaTeX-specific sense of the word. Use the `\urldef` macro to create a defined URL.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\urldef{\footurl}\url{http://www.this-is-a-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-long.url/}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\footnote{\footurl} % use the "defined URL" in the argument of "\footnote"
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to use `\urldef` like this, but it does not work. :( I am using `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}`.

Comment: @Magne - Please elaborate on the "does not work" observation. (a) What exactly have you tried -- do please show the URL that you're trying to get typeset in a footnote, plus the `\urldef` instruction. (b) What is the precise nature of the does-not-work problem: Do you get an error message, a warning message, the URL doesn't get displayed, the footnote doesn't even show up, or something else?

Comment: I tried `\urldef{\footurl}\url{https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/chinas-plan-to-organize-its-whole-society-around-big-data-a-rating-for-everyone/2016/10/20/1cd0dd9c-9516-11e6-ae9d-0030ac1899cd_story.html}` with `\footnote{\footurl}` as in your example. No errors or warnings, footnote shows as usual, but without the intended linebreak.

Comment: @Magne - I have some doubts that `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` works flawlessly. For sure, if I use the setup shown in the answer above, i.e., if I type `\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}` before loading `hyperref`, the URL is typeset across three lines, without further ado.

Comment: If you load url with  `\usepackage` instead of `\PassOptionsToPackage`, won't that give you a `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url.` since `hyperref` also loads the `url` package?

Comment: @Magne - The minimal working example I posted above explicitly loads first `url` and second `hyperref`. For sure, it does not generate any "option clash" errors. I'm not surprised that errors crop up if one insists on a pursuing a different setup.

Comment: @Magne -- When loading both the `url` (or the recent `xurl`) package and the `hyperref` package, it's essential to load `url` *before* `hyperref`. Nothing could will come from ignoring this rule.

Comment: I was actually always loading `url` before `hyperref`, just like in your example. Might be something else that was tripping it up, I don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  anyways, thanks for your time. I went with @ffl's solution for the time being.

Answer (score 7):

Or – not fancy but effective – simply replace the hyphens in the URL by "\%2D". It doesn't look as nice as hyphens, but this way it breaks correctly and still works fine as a link.

E.g.

```
\url{http://www.whysomanyhyphens.com/content/this-article-has-its-whole-title-as-the-url-that-will-never-fit-in-your-puny-footnote}
```

becomes

```
\url{http://www.whysomanyhyphens.com/content/this\%2Darticle\%2Dhas\%2Dits\%2Dwhole\%2Dtitle\%2Das\%2Dthe\%2Durl\%2Dthat\%2Dwill\%2Dnever\%2Dfit\%2Din\%2Dyour\%2Dpuny\%2Dfootnote}
```

Especially when the url is long and cryptic (=ugly) anyway, I just do that.

Comment: Can you please add an MWE?

Comment: \%2D does not work for me, just displays as "\%2D"

Answer (score 1):

My solution simply defines a new command which is capable of separating the URL at any position. 
I make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458125/2084944) solution, by formating every character as `texttt` and appending `\hskip 0pt plus 1pt`. The following example code defines the command `urlx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% TT every character and hyphenate after it
\def\hyphenateAndTtWholeString #1{\xHyphenate#1$\wholeString\unskip}

\def\xHyphenate#1#2\wholeString {\if#1$%
    \else\transform{#1}%
    \takeTheRest#2\ofTheString\fi}

\def\takeTheRest#1\ofTheString\fi
{\fi \xHyphenate#1\wholeString}

\def\transform#1{\url{#1}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt}

% Define the \urlx command which works like \url, but with line brakes
\def\urlx #1{\href{#1}{\hyphenateAndTtWholeString{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{Test: \urlx{http://www.this-is-a-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-long.de/}}

\end{document}
```

**Produces:**
[image: Output of urlx command]

**Explanation:**
By typing e.g. `\urlx{www.tt.net}`, the command produces actually:
`\href{www.tt.net}{\texttt{w}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{w}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{w}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{.}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{t}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{t}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{.}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{n}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{e}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt\texttt{t}\hskip 0pt plus 1pt}`

Comment: Works nice, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following package:

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

Comment: Might want to add a little explanation as to why. But I agree, nowadays xurl is probably better