# Line breaking and long URL strings

Tags: line-breaking, urls, apa-style

I'm an B.Sc. in industrial engineering student who decided to grab a B.Sc. in finance as well and I'm currently working on my B.Sc. thesis in finance regarding risk management in mortage houses. The rules state that I must use APA-style citation and bibliographies which has worked out OK so far.

When I was setting up my bibliography earlier today (which I have to manually because of lack of support for Icelandic in all the APA style packages I could find) I stumbled across the hanging package which worked perfectly except for one small failure.

This specific reference has a (rather) long url which contains a lot of hyphens which causes the line to break in a silly way. I can't seem to find a way around this so I was hoping someone might be able to help me out.

Here's how the code looks in my document (just this one reference, everything else worked fine):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hanging}
\selectlanguage{icelandic} 


\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{0.7cm}{1}
Glover, J. \& Chassany, A.S. (08.05.2012) Greek Default Risk Returns as Bond 
Maturity Nears. \textit{Bloomberg}. Sótt 11. febrúar 2013 af:     
\url{http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-05-08/greek-default-risk-returns-as-bond-maturity-nears.html}
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You may want to load `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before `hyperref`

Comment: Thank you sir! I have no idea why I hadn't thought of that..

Comment: The problem is very similar to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23394/url-linebreak-in-footnote Do you mind if we close the question by linking to that?

Comment: I don't mind at all.