# Acronym wrapped at end of page causes page number and header of next page to have same hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, fancyhdr

A bit of a confusing title perhaps, so let me explain. I'm using the packages `glossaries`, `hyperref` and `fancyhdr`. Acronyms defined with `glossaries` have a hyperlink to their definition. However when the acronym is wrapped at the end of a page and continues on the next, the page number of the first, and the header of the next page get the same hyperlink as the acronym.

I've made a simple document that will reproduce the problem. I noticed that the page number is not affected in this example. I'll have to test further to find out what else I need to include in the example to reproduce that part.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{dolor}{DA}{Dolor At}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\printglossaries

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent viverra eleifend mi, eget adipiscing velit. Aenean mauris diam, viverra vestibulum aliquam id, malesuada ut purus. Ut laoreet commodo turpis, et ullamcorper arcu aliquam eu. In egestas, augue vel malesuada aliquam, purus sem luctus felis, et aliquet metus neque id ligula. Etiam interdum vehicula rhoncus. Cras posuere lectus vel erat semper aliquet. Morbi erat orci, aliquet ut mauris non, dapibus porttitor eros. Sed odio leo, tincidunt id urna sit amet, suscipit rhoncus sem. Aenean vel sapien lacus. Donec tincidunt dui non porttitor dignissim. Praesent dignissim suscipit elementum. Aliquam quis convallis dolor. Pellentesque hendrerit suscipit augue eget tempor.

Cras feugiat nisl nec euismod vestibulum. Cras placerat leo at leo iaculis, non facilisis purus congue. Donec ut mollis eros. Cras ac dolor dolor. Duis vel porta arcu, et consectetur nisi. Sed pellentesque purus quam, et sollicitudin felis eleifend non. Donec eget nisi quis dui sagittis faucibus ut non ipsum. Ut non pretium ligula.

Nullam pellentesque risus augue, rhoncus luctus leo blandit in. Cras tincidunt eros sed gravida consequat. Donec gravida ligula id venenatis varius. Vestibulum mollis scelerisque diam, non lobortis lorem tristique in. Integer tempus fermentum lacus, nec sollicitudin sem aliquam et. Cras id porta tortor. Integer consequat nisl dui, et sodales quam accumsan in.

Vestibulum vitae leo vel urna gravida congue a id magna. Pellentesque sit amet purus leo. Suspendisse viverra placerat neque, quis mollis sem fermentum et. Vivamus at pharetra dui. Phasellus scelerisque molestie diam vel vehicula. Mauris vel ligula in eros mattis aliquet. Praesent nec elit lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vitae nunc ut metus accumsan fringilla. Nunc porta tempus quam, sit amet molestie metus accumsan nec. Duis vitae metus sit amet est luctus aliquet. Aliquam quis lacus nisi. Phasellus quam mi, porta vel molestie id, ornare non lorem.

Praesent quis nibh at est dignissim ullamcorper. Curabitur viverra porttitor lacinia. Mauris dapibus a nulla vel euismod. Donec ut urna congue, ultrices velit quis, blandit lorem. Mauris vel leo porttitor, ornare ligula quis, interdum leo. Curabitur et dolor purus. Donec pellentesque nisl congue, commodo \gls{dolor}, volutpat sem. Suspendisse sollicitudin dapibus ligula, in vestibulum nulla ornare vitae. Proin tempus pretium lectus sed pretium. Nulla hendrerit lectus sed risus ornare, et aliquet tortor dignissim. Ut tempor justo nec nisi posuere, sed pharetra erat ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur feugiat vehicula. Aenean sed turpis sed mauris iaculis adipiscing eget eget nulla. Maecenas sed euismod lectus. Etiam ut lacus neque.

\end{document}
```

This is how the compiled example looks like:

[image: Example]

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148411/url-in-footnote-spans-two-pages

Comment: That might indeed be related Ethan. Unfortunately the work-around in that answer isn't applicable for my problem since I'm not working in a footnote.

Comment: Thanks to Nicola Talbot pointing out the problem isn't specific to `glossaries` I found the following question that matches mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54136/hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly

Answer (score 2):

This effect isn't specific to `glossaries` but occurs more generally:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
viverra eleifend mi, eget adipiscing velit. Aenean mauris diam,
viverra vestibulum aliquam id, malesuada ut purus. Ut laoreet
commodo turpis, et ullamcorper arcu aliquam eu. In egestas, augue
vel malesuada aliquam, purus sem luctus felis, et aliquet metus
neque id ligula. Etiam interdum vehicula rhoncus. Cras posuere
lectus vel erat semper aliquet. Morbi erat orci, aliquet ut mauris
non, dapibus porttitor eros. Sed odio leo, tincidunt id urna sit
amet, suscipit rhoncus sem. Aenean vel sapien lacus. Donec tincidunt
dui non porttitor dignissim. Praesent dignissim suscipit elementum.
Aliquam quis convallis dolor. Pellentesque hendrerit suscipit augue
eget tempor.

Cras feugiat nisl nec euismod vestibulum. Cras placerat leo at leo
iaculis, non facilisis purus congue. Donec ut mollis eros. Cras ac
dolor dolor. Duis vel porta arcu, et consectetur nisi. Sed
pellentesque purus quam, et sollicitudin felis eleifend non. Donec
eget nisi quis dui sagittis faucibus ut non ipsum. Ut non pretium
ligula.

Nullam pellentesque risus augue, rhoncus luctus leo blandit in. Cras
tincidunt eros sed gravida consequat. Donec gravida ligula id
venenatis varius. Vestibulum mollis scelerisque diam, non lobortis
lorem tristique in. Integer tempus fermentum lacus, nec sollicitudin
sem aliquam et. Cras id porta tortor. Integer consequat nisl dui, et
sodales quam accumsan in.

Vestibulum vitae leo vel urna gravida congue a id magna.
Pellentesque sit amet purus leo. Suspendisse viverra placerat neque,
quis mollis sem fermentum et. Vivamus at pharetra dui. Phasellus
scelerisque molestie diam vel vehicula. Mauris vel ligula in eros
mattis aliquet. Praesent nec elit lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vitae nunc ut metus accumsan
fringilla. Nunc porta tempus quam, sit amet molestie metus accumsan
nec. Duis vitae metus sit amet est luctus aliquet. Aliquam quis
lacus nisi. Phasellus quam mi, porta vel molestie id, ornare non
lorem.

Praesent quis nibh at est dignissim ullamcorper. Curabitur viverra
porttitor lacinia. Mauris dapibus a nulla vel euismod. Donec ut urna
congue, ultrices velit quis, blandit lorem. Mauris vel leo
porttitor, ornare ligula quis, interdum leo. Curabitur et dolor
purus. Donec pellentesque nisl congue, commodo
\hyperlink{dolor}{dolor At (DA)}, volutpat
sem. Suspendisse sollicitudin dapibus ligula, in vestibulum nulla
ornare vitae. Proin tempus pretium lectus sed pretium. Nulla
hendrerit lectus sed risus ornare, et aliquet tortor dignissim. Ut
tempor justo nec nisi posuere, sed pharetra erat ullamcorper.
Praesent consectetur feugiat vehicula. Aenean sed turpis sed mauris
iaculis adipiscing eget eget nulla. Maecenas sed euismod lectus.
Etiam ut lacus neque.

\end{document}
```

A possible workaround is to switch off hyperlinks on first use with the package option `hyperfirst=false`:

```
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}
```

That way, there's less likelihood of a hyperlink spanning a page break.

Comment: Thanks, but that switches off hyperlinks for all first uses of an acronym. Additionally it very well may not be a first time use of an acronym that spans a page break.

Comment: @Danio I think acronyms typically shouldn't be broken across lines, so it's not a good idea for the subsequent use acronyms to span a page break. You can switch off the hyperlink just for the problematic entry using the starred version `\gls*`. Another possibility is to create an acronym style where only the short form has a link in the first use format.