# Reference and biography indentation issue

Tags: bibliographies

I have added a reference in my latex template. The problem is shown in a picture below

[image]

If you see the last reference, it goes a bit leftwards. I have found that it appears only for the last reference, whichever, reference comes last. I think it is a possible template issue.

here is MWE

```
\documentclass{fcs}
\usepackage{bm}

\volumn{ }
\doi{ }
\articletype{REVIEW~ARTICLE}
\copynote{{\copyright} Higher Education Press and Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2012}
\ratime{Received month dd, yyyy; accepted month dd, yyyy}
\email{$\times\times\times\times@\times\times\times.\times\times\times$}
\title{$\bm{Frontiers~ of~ Computer~ Science}$\\[2mm] Instruction for authors}
\author{Firstname LASTNAME \xff $^{1,2}$}
\address{{1\quad Higher Education Press, Beijing 100029, China}\\
{2\quad Acadcmic Journal Division, Beijing 100029, China}}

\markboth{Front. Comput. Sci.}{Firstname LASTNAME: please insert running head here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}

\begin{abstract}
A short abstract of up to 300 words written in one
paragraph, clearly indicating the object and scope of the paper as
well as the results achieved, should appear on the first page. It
should be written using the abstract environment.
\end{abstract}

\Keywords{Up to 8 words separated by commas.}

\section{Introduction}

\noindent Frontiers of Computer Science is an international
peer-reviewed academic journal sponsored by the Ministry of
Education of China. The journal is jointly published by Higher
Education Press of China and Springer on a bimonthly basis in
English. Online versions are available through both
http://www.springerlink.com/content/11704 and
http://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs.

In-text citations must agree with the references in either numbering
or names and year. The references should be presented completely and
without mistakes, and should be the original publication. We use the
citation-sequence system, that is to number the citations according
to sequence of their first appearance. Journal names should be
spelled out in full. Examples are given in     \cite{KargerD,Mastroianni,SchlessingerD,ZhugeH}.

\Acknowledgements{The ``Acknowledgement section'' is the general
term for the list of contributions etc}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Mastroianni} Verta O. Mastroianni C, Talia D. A super-peer model for resource
discovery services in large-scale grids. Future Generation Computer
Systems, 2005, 21(8): 1235--1248

\bibitem{ZhugeH} Zhuge H. The Knowledge Grid. Singapore: World Scientific Publishing   Co., 2004

\bibitem{SchlessingerD}
Schlessinger D. Schaechter M. Bacterial toxins. In: Schaechter M,
Medoff G, Eisenstein BI, eds. Mechanisms of microbial disease. 2nd
ed. Baltimore: Williams and Wilkins, 1993, 162--175

\bibitem{KargerD}
Karger D. Ruhl M. Simple efficient load balancing algorithms for
peer-to-peer systems. In: Proceedings of Sixteenth Annual ACM
Symposium on Parallelism in Algorithm and Architectures. 2004,
36--40
\end{thebibliography}

%% \Biography{#1}{#2}
%% #1 is the file name of photo,
%% #2 is author's biography
\Biography{fcs-2}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}  

\end{document}
```

It also appears in following cases 1) if no biography 2) even if the bbibliograhy is added in this way `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{oo}`
What I understand after lot of R & D is that perhaps its a templates issue. Any way to solve it.

Here is the screenshot
[image]
Whatever the end line is, either a biography or a reference, this problem appears.

The FCS latex template could be downloaded at following URL: [journal.hep.com.cn/fcs/EN/column/column11258.shtml](http://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs/EN/column/column11258.shtml)

Comment: The link you provide gives a link to the journal's LaTeX templates that are coded as an .rar file. Are there any normal-format versions of the material?

Comment: @Mico If you unzip it there is a complete written example, with all figures in it. Plz check it again

Comment: @Bernard Please have a look....

Comment: I'm sorry: I can't reproduce the problem with your code. Could you give a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: @Bernard The above example is a minimal working example. If you download the rar file from journal page, there is a tex and pdf files in in it, explaining the requirements of journal. If you open that pdf file. Just on the last page you will see this problem i.e., the last line on the last page, beside the biography image is not right. Same happens with references, if we remove the biography. Did you get it?

Comment: Sorry again, but the .tex and .pdf files (called FCStemplate12, right?) have no problem, and the .pdf I get after compiling is exactly the same. The example image in your question is different from the template.

Comment: @Bernard The last edited picture i showed is taken from my template file. Its so strange that it appears here and not at yours... any reason for such a strange behaviour?

Comment: But your code doesn't even mention `Jean Carletta`, which appears as no 19 in the last picture!. Are we speaking of the same thing?

Comment: @Bernard somehow chat is not connecting. Well! I checked it again and i found that the original PDF file is correct. But when I compiled it with my Texmaker 4.1.1 (Miktek 2.9) this problem occurs. How to check which setting cause this? Something wrong with texmaker. I even checked it in sharelatex and same problem occurs. Any clues?

Comment: TeX Live 2014 here, with updates. I can reproduce the problem, i.e. cannot reproduce the original PDF (FCStemplate12) exactly. The differences are: the last line does not wrap around the Photo (as shown by Skipper07), and Acknowledgements appear in the middle of References.

Answer (score 9):

There is something wrong with the template.  I haven't been able to trace exactly what, but the problem of the final line applies to a number of situations.  I think it is caused by interaction with the `flushend` package; the `fcs.cls` is redefining a number of basic internals commands and `flushend` expects a certain number of standard definitions.

*Update 27/2/2016*

As pointed out in the other answer of @boutinma, the `flushend` package loaded by `fcs` and has a new option `keeplastbox` that fixes the issue.  No you can just write

```
\documentclass[keeplastbox]{fcs}
```

This works in edge cases too mentioned in the comments.

```
\documentclass[keeplastbox]{fcs}
\usepackage{bm}

\volumn{ }
\doi{ }
\articletype{REVIEW~ARTICLE}
\copynote{{\copyright} Higher Education Press and Springer-Verlag
Berlin Heidelberg 2012} 
\ratime{Received month dd, yyyy; accepted month dd, yyyy}
\email{$\times\times\times\times@\times\times\times.\times\times\times$}
\title{$\bm{Frontiers~ of~ Computer~ Science}$\\[2mm] Instruction for authors}
\author{Firstname LASTNAME \xff $^{1,2}$}
\address{{1\quad Higher Education Press, Beijing 100029, China}\\
{2\quad Acadcmic Journal Division, Beijing 100029, China}}

\markboth{Front. Comput. Sci.}{Firstname LASTNAME: please insert
running head here} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}

\begin{abstract}
A short abstract of up to 300 words written in one
paragraph, clearly indicating the object and scope of the paper as
well as the results achieved, should appear on the first page. It
should be written using the abstract environment.
\end{abstract}

\Keywords{Up to 8 words separated by commas.}

\section{Introduction}

Examples are given in
\cite{KargerD,Mastroianni,SchlessingerD,ZhugeH}.

\Acknowledgements{The ``Acknowledgement section'' is the general
term for the list of contributions etc}



\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Mastroianni} Verta O. Mastroianni C, Talia D. A super-peer
  model for resource discovery services in large-scale grids. Future
  Generation Computer Systems, 2005, 21(8): 1235--1248

\bibitem{ZhugeH} Zhuge H. The Knowledge Grid. Singapore: World
  Scientific Publishing Co., 2004

\bibitem{SchlessingerD} Schlessinger D. Schaechter M. Bacterial
  toxins. In: Schaechter M, Medoff G, Eisenstein BI, eds. Mechanisms
  of microbial disease. 2nd ed. Baltimore: Williams and Wilkins, 1993,
  162--175

\bibitem{KargerD} Karger D. Ruhl M. Simple efficient load balancing
  algorithms for peer-to-peer systems. In: Proceedings of Sixteenth
  Annual ACM Symposium on Parallelism in Algorithm and
  Architectures. 2004, 36--40
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

*New answer* (much simpler than the old)

A general fix is to add `\par\leavevmode` before the end of the document.  As `etoolbox` is already loaded this may be accomplished by issuing

```
\AtEndDocument{\par\leavevmode}
```

in the preamble.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{fcs}
\usepackage{bm}
\AtEndDocument{\par\leavevmode}

\volumn{ }
\doi{ }
\articletype{REVIEW~ARTICLE}
\copynote{{\copyright} Higher Education Press and Springer-Verlag
Berlin Heidelberg 2012} 
\ratime{Received month dd, yyyy; accepted month dd, yyyy}
\email{$\times\times\times\times@\times\times\times.\times\times\times$}
\title{$\bm{Frontiers~ of~ Computer~ Science}$\\[2mm] Instruction for authors}
\author{Firstname LASTNAME \xff $^{1,2}$}
\address{{1\quad Higher Education Press, Beijing 100029, China}\\
{2\quad Acadcmic Journal Division, Beijing 100029, China}}

\markboth{Front. Comput. Sci.}{Firstname LASTNAME: please insert
running head here} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}

\begin{abstract}
A short abstract of up to 300 words written in one
paragraph, clearly indicating the object and scope of the paper as
well as the results achieved, should appear on the first page. It
should be written using the abstract environment.
\end{abstract}

\Keywords{Up to 8 words separated by commas.}

\section{Introduction}

Examples are given in
\cite{KargerD,Mastroianni,SchlessingerD,ZhugeH}.

\Acknowledgements{The ``Acknowledgement section'' is the general
term for the list of contributions etc}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Mastroianni} Verta O. Mastroianni C, Talia D. A super-peer
  model for resource discovery services in large-scale grids. Future
  Generation Computer Systems, 2005, 21(8): 1235--1248

\bibitem{ZhugeH} Zhuge H. The Knowledge Grid. Singapore: World
  Scientific Publishing Co., 2004

\bibitem{SchlessingerD} Schlessinger D. Schaechter M. Bacterial
  toxins. In: Schaechter M, Medoff G, Eisenstein BI, eds. Mechanisms
  of microbial disease. 2nd ed. Baltimore: Williams and Wilkins, 1993,
  162--175

\bibitem{KargerD} Karger D. Ruhl M. Simple efficient load balancing
  algorithms for peer-to-peer systems. In: Proceedings of Sixteenth
  Annual ACM Symposium on Parallelism in Algorithm and
  Architectures. 2004, 36--40
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

This may add a single blank line at the end of the document, but does fix the bad line spacing.  Previous experimenting had lead me to finding that `\leavevmode` fixed the problem after lists and `thebibliogarphy`, but that `\par\leavevmode` was needed after the `\Biography` commands.  Really the class needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Andrew Swann is correct. The issue is caused by flushend in fcs.cls. To fix it, just replace "flushend" with "balance" in fcs.cls. Then, use ***/balance*** at any left column of the last page. I've successfully reproduce the the original PDF (FCStemplate12).

Comment: **\AtEndDocument{\par\leavevmode}** worked for me when the last reference was at the bottom of the right column. But when there document is a bit longer and the last line of the last reference is at the beginning of the next page (left column), it didn't work. Anyway, **\par\leavevmode** (at the end of the document) worked for me in both cases.

Comment: @Alisa Thank you for this remark.  The answer of boutinma points to the best way to deal with issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I include

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{flushend}
```

The problem is now fixed if I simply use the option `[keeplastbox]` like this:

```
\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}
```

Comment: This is a useful remark.  The newest version of `flushend` has this option.  To pass this option when the class loads the package just add it to the documentclass options.  This is the case for the `fcs` class, which what the OP is asking about, so writing `\documentclass[flushend]{fcs}` is the cleanest solution.

Comment: This works perfectly!