# Last reference misaligning. asmems4.bst

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using latex template for asme conferences.

The ***asmems4*** style is used for references.

The last reference gets misaligned as in figure. It does not matter what the last reference is. If I add another reference below it, the last one goes bad while the second last one, which was last previously, aligned itself. [image]
[image]

Please suggest what might be the problem.

Comment: the templet can be found here [http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/]

Comment: I would guess it is the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198287/15925 where passing an option to flushend fixes the problem.

Comment: OK, `flushend` is not used by your class, but adding `\par\leavemode` just before `\end{document}` might work.  If it doesn't please post some of your document code.

Comment: @AndrewSwann `\par \leavemode` did not work. It gave all sorts of error. But I was using `\flushend ` in my file. So used the technique in the link you shared i.e `\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}` . It worked.
Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.