# Need fcs.cls latex file

Tags: document-classes

I want the `fcs.cls` LaTeX class file. I tired online but I didn't get. I want to submit my paper but without `fcs.cls` file it is not running. If someone has ìt please send to me.

Thanks
N Sharma

Comment: you do not give any clues, you could rename `article.cls` to `fcs.cls`  but I suspect that isn't the answer you want? is FCS a journal? does it say there is a latex class of that name? is there a link to the author instructions?...

Comment: From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198287/reference-and-biography-indentation-issue: The FCS latex template could be downloaded at following URL: http://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs/EN/column/column11258.shtml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it ie solved by comments.