# Underscore in URL breaks link in pdf

Tags: footnotes, url, underscore

I have a footnote with a long url containing an underscore, like this:

```
\footnote{\url{http://www.example.com/somethinglong_somethingotherlong}}
```

The link appears in the pdf, but it is broken off after the underscore and redirects to `http://www.example.com/somethinglong_`, which of course gives a page not found error.

How do I solve this? Adding a \ before the underscore doesn't do anything (the backslash just shows up in the pdf). It seems that the same problem was encountered here

[URL linebreak in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23394/url-linebreak-in-footnote)

but I see no answer here as well.

EDIT: I can't use `hyperref`. Added MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ismir,amsmath,cite,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example? Are you using hyperref or not? If not then it is a previewer problem, where the previewer is trying to interpret the contents of the PDF and attempts to parse the URL and perhaps not doing a good job. In any case it helps if you provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Also it would be useful to have an *actual* working URL, so that we know when it's not working...

Comment: @rdv - I've posted a new answer to the query [URL linebreak in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23394/5001), to mention the use of "defined URLs" for URL strings that occur in the arguments of `\footnote` and similar directives. (`\thanks` is such a directive.)

Comment: 1. What is ismir package? 2. Without hyperref the issue you see was explained by @daleif hours ago: there is no hyperlink in the PDF, and it is entirely up to the PDF viewer to detect it. I can reproduce your issue by shifting the `\url` so that it breaks at the underscore.

Comment: @jfbu The ismir package is the styleguide that we have to follow. It's not relevant, sorry. I was actually avoiding to use `hyperref` - I don't want these ugly boxes around the references...

Comment: Are you aware of the `hidelinks` option for hyperref?

Comment: @rdv these ugly boxes do not show in the printed on paper PDF, and you can always customize their presence on screen. RTFM.

Answer (score 6):

Typesetting URL strings in footnotes is known to be tricky at times. It's best to use a defined-URL macro in such cases, using the `\urldef` machinery of the `url` package.

[image]

Feel free to load the `hyperref` package as well, so that clicking on the URL string (in a suitable pdf browser, naturally) takes you to the URL in question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\urldef{\footurl}\url{http://www.example.com/somethinglong_somethingotherlong}

\begin{document}
\footnote{\footurl}  % Use a "defined-URL macro" in the argument of "\footnote"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: @rdv - "with the same result" -- what do you mean?! The code I posted in my answer works perfectly with the URL string you posted. If the code doesn't work for you, it must be because your code differs in some important ways from mine. E.g., what's the *real* URL string you're using? Also, please indicate whether or not you  load the `hyperref` package and, if so, how you load it.

Comment: @Mico, trying to convey the spirit of this site, may I politely ask you "How is that an answer?". The OP did not complain about a problem with typesetting or breaking the URL, but the fact that from using his/her/its PDF viewer, the hyperlink was truncated. That has nothing to do with typesetting problems your answer is addressing. (notice that I do elaborate on my "How is that an answer?".)

Comment: @jfbu - My answer addressed the information the OP provided. If the OP is working with something else, my answer is probably less than fully useful. I'll admit freely to having no psychic capabilities whatsoever. If what the OP posted isn't relevant to the OP, there's nothing I can do about it. Does this address your question?

Comment: @Mico, by 'same results' I mean that it breaks in the pdf at the exact same place - after the underscore. I copied your code literally, and it still happens! I'm using the Wikipedia url string, and I am not using the `hyperref`package.

Comment: @Mico And for the record: your answer is helpful (unlike jfbu's remarks making this comment thread messy...)

Comment: Oh, and if this wasn't clear: also without using `hyperref` I can click the other urls in my pdf.

Comment: @rdv I made only one remark not "remarks" and you can always flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Mico, yes thanks. It does address exactly my question.

Comment: @rdv - If you can click on URLs in your LaTeX-produced pdf file without having loaded the `hyperref` package, it must be because your pdf browser can recognize URLs on its own and make them "active", i.e., clickable. But that's clearly a pdf browser capability, quite separate from LaTeX and any packages which may (or may not) have been loaded.

Comment: @Mico - Aha! Learned something new today :) I just added the hyperref package as follows `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`, but this gives me the error 'Option clash for package url. \urldef' at the line starting with `\urldef`... Also, with or without hyperref, my LaTeX editor (TeXstudio) complains that `\footurl` is an 'unrecognized command' - although that doesn't stop it from compiling. One way or another, I'm afraid your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @rdv - Do you load `hyperref` before or after `url`? (Hint: `hyperref` *must* be loaded after `url`.) Separately, instead of `hidelinks`, try `colorlinks,allcolors=black`. Finally, if `\footurl` isn't a recognized command, it's almost certainly because you didn't run the `\urldef` instruction exactly as I showed in my answer.

Comment: @Mico - I tried both. I also copy-pasted your example verbatim - it just doesn't work for me... Too bad, I can't afford to waste anymore time on this!

Comment: @rdv - FWIW, it's been rather difficult to figure out what you actually do. In fact, I'm quite sure that I still don't understand what's going on in your document. In retrospect, my mistake was to even attempt to provide an answer without having made you provide all relevant information. Given these failures to communicate, I'm not surprised that you weren't able to resolve the issue that led to you to post this query. Sorry.

Comment: @Mico - no need to apologise! You tried :) It just hit me what might be the reason of our confusion: my text has two columns per page (as defined in the ismir package, I assume). In the MWE I left that package out, resulting in one single column per page and a valid, non-split link. Using two columns, however, it doesn't fit anymore. For some strange reason I cannot reproduce the error in a new MWE using two columns - there, the link works as it should. My old example still doesn't, however.