# Is this a privacy concern when adding URL to footnote when generating PDF?

Tags: footnotes, pdf, url, privacy

I am writing a **completely anonymous** PDF criticism to a paper, and I added a footnote which links to a video to support my arguments. However, when I click on the link in Adobe Reader, a warning is created which shows the path of link and the path contains my FIRST AND LAST NAME (blanked out and truncated).  I can reproduce this privacy intrusion on multiple other PDF readers such as SumatraPDF.

**Is this a warning that is only displayed to my system or is it displayed for anyone who sees the PDF?** Why would the entire path be embedded for the hyperlink?

[image]

Comment: How did you include the URL in the PDF?

Comment: \footnote{\url{www..........}}

Comment: or same as: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23394/url-linebreak-in-footnote?rq=1

Comment: because you omitted the https:// you are linking to a local file on your system in a folder www/youtube of your current directory so the issue is not only privacy: the link will not work.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\href{<URL>}{<text>}` instead of only `\url`, as in

```
\href{http://youtube.com/watch?v=aztd}{\texttt{youtube.com/watch?v=aztd}}
```

with an explicit `http://` protocol directive.

Comment: I don't know anything about latex, but what I know about URLs, HTTP, and TLS tells me that it should be `https` and not `http`. I should note that I don't think that this will affect op's anonymity, but https is much more secure in other respects.